# UICollectionViewCell does not autosize subviews at first appearance

Tags: uicollectionview, ios8, xcode6, uicollectionviewcell, autosize

With XCode 6 and iOS 8 I encountered the problem that `UICollectionViewCell`s does not autolayout / autoresize the subviews at first appearance. Once they have been shown and the cell is reused everything is fine.

Answer (score 3):

I put

```
[cell layoutIfNeeded];
```

after the `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier`-Statement and everything was fine again.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I tried to put `[cell layoutIfNeeded];`, but when I refresh the tableview, not all the cells are refreshed. 
With the code `[cell layoutSubviews];` just before returning the cell, all cells are updated every time. Here is the complete piece of code

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
MyCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:kCellID forIndexPath:indexPath];
...
[cell layoutSubviews];
return cell;
}
```